# How can I add my input text box to my link params?

Tags: html, dom, grails, input, gsp

I have the following in my `shop.gsp` file:

```
<input type="text" class="inputTextBox" name="queryString"/>
<g:link action="shop" controller="item" params='[queryString:
"${document.getElementById('queryString').value}", queryType: "search"]'>
 Search
 </g:link>
```

But in my controller when I do a `params.queryString` it returns an empty string.I know I could be using a form for this but for my problem I need to use the link like it is. So how can I get the value of my input text in the link parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this with the use of some jQuery. Off the top of my head, so please forgive any typos.

```
<input id="field" name="field" type="text" value="" />
<g:link class="mylink" controller="somewhere" action="something">My link</g:link>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    $("a.mylink").on("click", function(e) {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?field=" + $("#field").val();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How would I grab it in my controller then?

Comment: In my example the controller would see that as params.field having whatever value was in the field input.

Comment: For some reason it never enters onclick function... Maybe because searchLink isn't render by the time the function executes?